Norm of a simple extension
We have the following setup: $K$ a field $L= K( a)$ algebraic field extension and $m_a$ its minimal polynomial. We need to show that for each $x\in K$ we have: $m_a(x) = N_{L/K}(x-a)$.
I just plugged in the definition i.e take a basis of $L$ i.e $(1,a,\dots, a^{n-1})$ for $[L:K]=n$.
Then look at $\varphi: L \to L$ given by multiplication of $(x-a)$. Then by definition the norm we are searching is the determinant of $\varphi$. But $\varphi(a^i) = x a^i -a^{i+1}$ so the matrix has on the diagonal always $x$ and on the subdiagonal always $-1$ right? So the Determinant will be $x^n$, but something went wrong this cant be the minimal polynomial of $a$ in general right?

What is $f$ in the second sentence? It isn't clear what the problem statement is.

sorry $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ I corrected it

For $i=n-1$ you have $\phi(a^{n-1})=xa^{n-1}-a^n$, but $a^n$ isn't in you basis, so that last matrix column is not as you described.

As commented by @Daniel5803, the mistake was in the calculation of the last column of the matrix, because $\phi(a^{n-1})=xa^{n-1}-a^n$ but $a^n$ is not in your basis.
Let us first prove the special case $x=0$. If $m_a(X)=X^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_kX^k$,
$$N_{L/K}(-a)=\begin{vmatrix}0&\dots&\dots&\dots&\alpha_0\\
-1&0&\dots&\dots&\alpha_1\\0&-1&0&\dots&\alpha_2\\\vdots
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\dots&0&-1&\alpha_{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}=\alpha_0=m_a(0)$$
(see Companion matrix).
From this, we derive the general case: let $b:=a-x$. Then, $m_b(X)=m_a(X+x)$ hence
$$N_{L/K}(x-a)=N_{L/K}(-b)=m_b(0)=m_a(x).$$
